# Where is stddef.h in Linux？

Tags: command-line

where is stddef.h in Linux？I use order that locate stddef.h to find the file. But when I open the file，it is empty.I want to know why and where is stddef.h in Linux.Thanks.

Comment: See [Why /usr/include/linux/stddef.h is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31285400/4440445)